# RoR - installing gem - libxml-ruby-1.1.4

Tags: rubygems, bundler, libxml2, libxml-ruby

I'm trying install libxml-ruby-1.1.4 (via Bundler, but same thing happens when I do a gem install) and I get a huge list of errors.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6 on a Unibody MacBook.

The errors start after the make and have a lot of DARWI errors and then a long list of ruby_xml_error … undeclared (first use in this function).

Here is a [pastie](http://pastie.org/1619222) with all of the errors.

Please help.

---

In order to help with others searching for this issue here are some of the common phrases showing up in the errors.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"

ruby_xml_error ... undeclared (first use in this function)

XML_(blah)

(No such file or directory)

make: *** [ruby_xml_error.o] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not the only one with this [issue](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ruby_xml_error+site%3ahttp://rubyforge.org/pipermail/libxml-devel/&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).  Common problem is an old version of libxml2.

```
brew install libxml2
```

And then make sure the libxml2 bin is in your path.